# How to avoid multiple driver.findElement calls on the same web element?

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am using PageObject pattern for my selenium webdriver+TestNG framework. 

In my pageObject classes I have multiple methods where I am using driver.findElement to find the same webelement present on the same page.
For example:

```
 public class HomePage extends BasePage {
        private WebElement searchField;
        private String searchFieldLocator;


        HomePage(WebDriver driverFromTest, CustomLogger loggerFromTest,
                HashMap<String, String> testDataMapFromTest)
        {
            super(driverFromTest, loggerFromTest, testDataMapFromTest);
            searchFieldLocator = testDataMap.get("searchFieldLocator");

        }


        public void method1()
      {

        searchField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(searchFieldLocator));
        searchField.sendKeys("foo");

      }


      public void method2()
      {
         searchField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(searchFieldLocator));
         searchField.sendKeys("bar");
      }
```

**My questions are:**
1. How can I avoid using driver.findElement on the same WebElement variables multiple times. I want a way where once I find the webelement, I'll just use the variable in any other method without using driver.findElement. I have read about PageFactory where you can use @FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = "locatorstring") with @CacheLookup annotation. Is it what I need? Does CacheLookup use driver.findElement only once and re-uses the reference?
2. Secondly, does it become memory intensive when you perform driver.findElements too many times for the same web-element? Is this micro-optimization that I don't need to worry about?

I thought of a way to avoid doing driver.findElement on the same web element by writing a method  like this:

```
 protected WebElement getWebElement(By by, String elementName) {
        WebElement element;

        if(webElementMap.get(elementName)==null)
        {
           element = driver.findElement(by);
           webElementMap.put(elementName, element);
        }
        else
            element = webElementMap.get(elementName);

        return element;

    }
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

@CacheLookup does use driver.findElement only once and re-uses the reference.

Watch out though you may start coming accross StaleElementReferenceException's

Comment: Ok, what about my second question??

Comment: Also, so would it be good to use FindBy and CacheLookup only for elements that are static on the webpage and not for dynamic elements?

Comment: In regards to it being memory intensive, do you have any problems with the amount of memory used by your tests (I can't say I ever have so I've never tried to measure it).  I don't bother with @CacheLookup personally but I would suggest using it on static elements would be the way to go if you are going to use it.

Comment: My test suite is pretty large with a large number of PageObject classes. I have a problem of webdriver just randomly failing during driver.findElement calls so I thought I should check if too many driver.findElement calls is causing it. I haven't measured the memory usage too.

Comment: Define randomly failing.  Currently I have a very large test framework with a lot of page object classes but we have no issues with findElement calls.  Before you start optimising for memory usage check that this is indeed an issue, to quote Donald Knuth "**Premature optimisation is the root of all evil**"

Comment: make them private methods that you can reference outside such as "private WebElement getButton { return driver.findelement....; }".  Then reference the method in your test instead.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple calls can be a problem when using a Grid provider such as Saucelabs.

Each Webdriver command results in a API call so the following would make two API calls;

```
searchField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(searchFieldLocator));
searchField.sendKeys("foo");
```

Requests to the Grid will be magnitudes slower then user a specific driver such as ChromeDriver so you have to consider this when writing tests which may potentially use Grid.  Caching objects is way to achieve this.

However, if you cache objects, you are likely to hit `StaleObject` issues, so you to quote Kenny Rogers;

> "You got to know when to hold 'em, know when to fold 'em"

I personally stay away from the `@FindBy` and `@CacheLookup` annotations as I want to have control of caching strategy

Comment: so is it okay to call driver.findElements as many times I want, than to use cacheLookup? As of now, I am not using selenium grid.

Comment: Yes, I don't believe you will face any performance issues if u you create the object over and over again